# AmbientLight display differences

Tags: three.js, jackson

I tried to illuminate the model with `AmbientLight` of `three.js`. I used the same light source in the test environment and the production environment, but found that the color rendering was different. The whole process I sorted out couldn't find the difference.

```
let ambColor = new THREE.Color('rgb(255, 255, 255)');
    this.ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(ambColor)
    this.scene.add(this.ambientLight)
```

**Test environment:**

[image]

**Production environment:**
[image]

The test environment was obviously brighter, and I also tried turning off the `AmbientLight` to make sure the lights did work.

[image]

[example file](https://gitlab.com/po_developer/high-precision-3d-graphics-of-traditional-buildings/-/tree/master/f5155b03-db96-414b-a612-c1bf64311644)

Answer (score 0):

Check where you call your renderer, you might be using one of these:

```js
//Physically Correct Lights 
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true

//In your update function, maybe removed the env map from the scene, but forgot about removing it from your update function too.
if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh && child.material instanceof THREE.MeshStandardMaterial){
   child.material.envMap = environmentMap
}

//Output encoding (by default is LinearEncoding)
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.LinearEncoding

//Tone mapping (by default is NoToneMapping)
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.NoToneMapping
```

If not, try removing everything in both environements but the models and lights. Check if the three.js version is the same.

PD: Try using more [light](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=light#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) sources and shadows, you will get a better result.

Ambient light:
[image]

Ambient light + Point light:
[image: Ambient light + Point light]

This was free content available on [Bruno Simon's course](https://threejs-journey.com/lessons/15#directionallight)

Comment: what's the `child`? I tried adding the remaining three variables and the model is darker than the original... Adding multiple light sources looks good. But I'm dealing with multiple models, each of which is very different in size, if I want to add multiple lights, I have to find a way to figure out(calculate?) which coordinates to place the lights on individually.

Comment: I checked two environment three.js versions, `"three": "^0.144.0"`(production) and `"three": "^0.132.2"`(test).

Comment: I tried version 0.132.2 in the production environment, and the light color is also dark.

Comment: I can only think of removing everything in the scene but the model and a light source that is the exact same in both environments and in the process, you will end up finding the issue.

Comment: I've tried removing everything, leaving just the ambient light, still can't see the difference..